# I just need to escape single quote in DECODE Function in oracle, need help on this?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Here is my code : When I a'm testing with single quote for fields `name` and `gender` getting the below exception:

```
}
    sql = "SELECT * FROM dummy.employee_details " + "WHERE name = decode('" + name + "','',name,'" + name
                    + "') AND " + "fname = decode('" + fname + "','',fname,'" + fname + "') AND " + "gender = decode('"
                    + gender + "','',gender,'" + gender + "') AND " + "Age = decode(" + Age + ",null,Age," + Age
                    + ") AND " + "startDate = decode(to_date('" + query_date
                    + "','yyyy-mm-dd'),'null',startDate,to_date('" + query_date + "','yyyy-mm-dd')) AND "
                    + "salary = decode(" + salary + ",null,salary," + salary + ")";
} else {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM dummy.employee_details " + "WHERE name = decode('" + name + "','',name,'" + name
                    + "') AND " + "fname = decode('" + fname + "','',fname,'" + fname + "') AND " + "gender = decode('"
                    + gender + "','',gender,'" + gender + "') AND " + "Age = decode(" + Age + ",null,Age," + Age
                    + ") AND " + "salary = decode(" + salary + ",null,salary," + salary + ")";
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
    at com.fadel.model.dao.impl.EmployeeDAOImpl.advanceSearch(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:177)
    at com.fadel.model.bo.Impl.EmployeeBOImpl.advanceSearch(EmployeeBOImpl.java:47)
    at com.fadel.model.view.backing.EmployeeController.listEmployees(EmployeeController.java:151)
    at com.fadel.model.view.backing.EmployeeController.getEmployees(EmployeeController.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor483.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.getValue(UISequence.java:180)
    at org.richfaces.component.UISequence.createExtendedDataModel(UISequence.java:114)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTableBase.createExtendedDataModel(UIDataTableBase.java:194)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:467)
    at org.richfaces.component.UIDataAdaptor.getRowCount(UIDataAdaptor.java:518)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor414.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2387)
    at org.richfaces.DataScrollerUtils.eval(DataScrollerUtils.java:86)
    at org.richfaces.DataScrollerUtils.getRowCount(DataScrollerUtils.java:81)
    at org.richfaces.event.DataTablePreRenderListener.processEvent(DataTablePreRenderListener.java:124)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:856)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.context.MetaComponentEncodingVisitCallback.visit(MetaComponentEncodingVisitCallback.java:83)
    at org.richfaces.context.BaseExtendedVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(BaseExtendedVisitContext.java:103)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedRenderVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(ExtendedRenderVisitContext.java:65)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1701)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(Unknown Source)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.processPartial(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:264)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1857)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Error : 938, Position : 120, Sql = SELECT * FROM dummy.employee_details WHERE name = decode('','',name,'') AND fname = decode('','',fname,'') AND gender = decode(''','',gender,''') AND Age = decode(null,null,Age,null) AND salary = decode(null,null,salary,null), OriginalSql = SELECT * FROM dummy.employee_details WHERE name = decode('','',name,'') AND fname = decode('','',fname,'') AND gender = decode(''','',gender,''') AND Age = decode(null,null,Age,null) AND salary = decode(null,null,salary,null), Error Msg = ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 96 more
```

Comment: Use parametrized query

Comment: Do not concatenate strings. **Apply** parameters using `?`  instead, and you won't need to deal with escaping strings ever.

Comment: Alex, The Impaler Thanx for answers, can you please let me know how to use advanced quoting system q'[]' in DECODE function, that will be helpful here to resolve the isuue.

Comment: Bind your variables. BIND YOUR VARIABLES! Seriously, why expose your code to SQL Injection when you can bind your variables... as has already been suggested? Also, the database will thank you, as it doesn't have to do a hard parse for the query each time you pass new values in. Don't concatenate your values; bind 'em.

Answer (score 0):

Check at this:

select 'kober''s guy' as name from dual;--print kober's guy

you could use in ur code a simple replace

name = name.replace("'","''");